# error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing pylibbvg

Tags: python

I'm installing pylibvg, and I get many links with similar error but for different installations.  I tried a few things but keep getting the error.  Basically, I am trying to run: `sudo python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

I have already successfully executed following:

```
pip install cython
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Any ideas why I'm getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this error could have been encountered because of lack of memory.

As wuan mentioned "https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1880" following the steps to create a swapfile helped me to get over my issue. You can see if it helps you out.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=524288
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Python.h is nothing but a header file. It is used by gcc to build applications. You need to install a package called python-dev. This package includes header files, a static library and development tools for building Python modules, extending the Python interpreter or embedding Python in applications. To install this package, enter:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

or

```
$ apt-get install python-dev
```

ref: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-python-h-file-not-found-error-solution/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was to install several extra packages,

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev libffi-dev build-essential
```

[source](https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools)